# ngMessages and Nested Scopes - Datepicker in an ngForm on a Tab

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-messages

**OP Update**

I've figured out the problem and this issue is now closed. Would one day like to find the time to post the solution as an answer here.

---

I'm having a bit of an issue working with ngMessages inside an ng-form on an Angular Bootstrap tab. Further complicating things, the thing I am validating is a Angular Bootstrap datepicker. So the code is as follows, and as you can see, I've got a datepicker on an ng-form which is on a Tab.

```
<uib-tab index="5" heading="{{tabs[5].title}}" select="changeCheck($event)">
    <ng-form name="{{tabs[5].form}}">
        <div class="col-md-9">
        ...     
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4>Add Followup</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="addFollowupDate" class="control-label">Date:</label>                    
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="addFollowupDate"
                               class="form-control"
                               uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                               ng-required="true"
                               ng-model="newFollowup.date"
                               is-open="addFollowupPopup.opened"
                               datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                               close-text="Close"
                               alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openAddFollowupPopup()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                        </span>
                        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="followupsForm.newFollowup.date.$error" ng-if="followupsForm.newFollowup.date.$invalid && followupsForm.newFollowup.date.$touched">
                            <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I've assigned that form to the scope using the following line:

```
$scope.followupsForm = $('ng-form[name="followupsForm"]').data('$formController');
```

And I have successfully set the control to touched on a submit which does make the border go red:

```
if ($scope.followupsForm.$invalid) {

    angular.forEach($scope.followupsForm.$error, function (formErrorField) {
        angular.forEach(formErrorField, function (errorField) {
            errorField.$setTouched(); // by setting to touched, the relevant message will display if the field is invalid.
        });
    });
}
```

But the ng-message for required does not display.

Any ideas why? Could be a tough one with nested scopes etc. (of the tab and the picker).